# Python re function

Tags: python

I've been racking my brain as how to do the following:

If I have a sting of data such as `"003     HELLO, banana apple,xyz    004    HELLI, pear peach,lmn"`
I have a whole document full of rows like this which need splitting into:

```
003     HELLO, banana apple,xyz
004     HELLI, pear peach,lmn
```

To me the logical thing to do would be to split the line after the word following the second comma as this is a pattern that runs all the way through.

Surely there has to be a way to do this with the re function.

Any idea how to do this?

Many thanks everyone

Comment: What are you trying to extract from each line?

Answer (score 0):

Can you be more specific on what you are expecting as an outcome? If you are trying to split a bunch of rows into a list you could always use `.split( '\n' )`.

Comment: Questions like this should probably be comments, and not answers.

Comment: @DSM I agree with you, but it actually is a question in an answer. :b

Comment: True, but since the original string doesn't have any `\n`s in it, the answer wouldn't work anyway. :^)

Comment: The *target* has linebreaks.  The original string doesn't have any now and doesn't seem to have ever had any.  Or am I missing something?

Comment: I stand corrected. I guess the edit just provided linebreaks for readability sake. @DSM you win this one... ;)

Answer (score 0):

To iterate over the whole file, you can do something like this:

```
lines = []

with open('file.txt', 'r') as handle:
  for line in handle:
    lines.append(line.split(',')[-1].strip())

print lines
```

I'm a bit confused as to what you're trying to extract from the file, so if that gets clarified my answer might become invalid.

Answer (score 0):

perhaps this

```
import re
result = re.findall(["[^,\s]*,[^,]*,\S*", data)
```

for example

> > > re.findall(["[^,\s]*,[^,]*,\S*", "003 HELLO, banana apple,xyz 004 HELLI, pear peach,lmn") 
> > >          ['003 HELLO, banana apple,xyz','004 HELLI, pear peach,lmn']

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use a regular expression to extract the number. Here's an example:

```
import re

s = '003 HELLO, banana apple,xyz'

m = re.match(r'^(\d+) ', s)
if m:
    digits = m.group(1)
    value = int(digits)
    print "{} : `{}`".format(value, s[len(digits):].strip())
else:
    print "Invalid format"
```

The regular expression looks like `^(\d+)` and can be explained as:

- start of string `^`
- a group `(...)`
- a digit `\d`
- ...repeated 1+ times `+`
- a space

Later on the value of the matched group (i.e. the digit) is extracted using `m.group(1)`.